# JQuery - Restore Element That was Replaced

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have button **edit** and button **save**. When I click on the **edit** button it replaces my element with a `textbox` or `textarea`. If I click button **save**, which uses another function, how can I restore the element to what it was before `replaceWith()`?

```
<div class="will-be-turned-into-texbox"></div>

function edit(){
    // Replace above div with texbox
}

function save_edit(){
    // Change back texbox to the original div
}
```

Comment: Is that all the code you have so far? If not, please post a complete code example.

Comment: instead of replacing why not just hide/show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [`replaceWith` docs](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/), there's a hint:

> **Description**: Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content and *return the set of elements that was removed*.

*(My emphasis)*

So...store the return value, and when you want to put it back, put it back using `append` or (indeed) `replaceWith` again.

Gratuitous example:

```js
var replaced;
$(document).on("click", "#replace", function() {
  // Save what's being replaced
  replaced = $(this).replaceWith('<button id="restore">Restore</button>');
});
$(document).on("click", "#restore", function() {
  // Restore it
  $(this).replaceWith(replaced);
});
```

```html
<button id="replace">Replace</button>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Note the use of delegated event handlers, to avoid having to reconnect things.

Comment: @tjcrowder thank you for your reply. The problem lies in that I have both functions outside `$(document).ready()` and wanted to avoid saving the replaced element in a global variable.

Comment: @user3704920: You could store it on the replacement element using `data`. Or wrap your functions in a scoping function (I always do). Or if you're going to want to put it back, why not just *hide* it instead of replacing it?

Comment: @t.jcrowder having a scope function is a good idea. Really appreciate your input.